# Beginner with a problem using recursion in Python

Tags: python, function, recursion

The exercise is to create a recursive function that accepts another function and an argument.  I've encountered an semantic error, and my function is not doing what I had hoped it would do.  I'm a beginner, so this may be a very easy fix, but I can't seem to find it.  Thank you for any help you can provide:

```py
def do_this(func, arg):   # this function will call another function (func) a maximum of (arg) times
                          
    arg -= 1              # in order to ensure that we call (func) only (arg) times, I reduce (arg) by 1 
                           #to start
    if arg <= 0:
        return
    else:
        do_this(func, arg) # here is where the recursion takes place when this function calls itself - if 
                           # this is written correctly, then this function will call itself (arg) times


def print_n(s, n):        # this function is also recursive, it will print the arguments passed to it 
                          #from the function 'do_this'
      if n <= 0:          # each time it completes a cycle of 'n' iterations it will print the bundle 
                          #number
        x = 1
        print("Bundle Number", x)
        x += 1
        return
      else:
        print(s)
        print_n(s, n - 1)

do_this(print_n("hello", 2), 4)
```

This should print the following:

```
hello
hello
Bundle Number 1
hello
hello
Bundle Number 2
hello
hello
Bundle Number 3
hello
hello
Bundle Number 4
```

Comment: At no stage does `do_this` call its `func` param.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) The point about using a debugger to step through your code is especially helpful: it lets you see _exactly_ what each line of your program does.

Comment: Furthermore, you aren't passing a function to `do_this` in your driver code: `do_this(print_n("hello", 2), 4)`, you are passing the *result of calling* `print_n("hello", 2), 4)` which is `None`, not a function

Answer (score 2):

`do_this` calls itself but never actually calls `func`.

Also, you shouldn't pass parameters to `print_n` before passing it to `do_this` - you should pass the function itself along with all the data you need to perform the calls. Passing parameters will cause the call to `print_n` to be actually executed. Normally, the return value of `print_n` would then be passed to `do_this`, except that there is no return value.

Remember, you want to pass `print_n` itself to `do_this`, not just the result of `print_n`.

Answer (score -2):

I noticed a small issue in your code. It appears that the func isn't being called as expected, likely due to how you're passing print_n("hello", 2) to do_this.

For a solution, consider using a lambda function or directly referencing print_n. Additionally, if you're interested in a deeper understanding, exploring Asymptotic Analysis could be valuable. You can find a helpful introduction about it here https://youtu.be/BpiMRyWoDu0?si=tvyj-56gUmjt0p0r .

Understanding this concept may provide insights into why passing functions in this way can behave unexpectedly. Feel free to reach out if you have any questions or need further clarification. Happy coding!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35275040)